# Show Images from DB with Word-Search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am writing on a basic Image Script that shows up all images with a specific keyword.
I already have a database with ~650 images. The Structure is:

```
id, int(100), auto_increment
topstory, varchar(255), unique  [this is the image URL, unique so there won't be doubles]
tags, longtext  [the keywords will be separated by a comma or something]
```

What I basically need is an Idea on how to do this. I want an Input where I can type in whatever I want (e.g. "nature") and then display all images with that keyword. I could use jqueryui.autocomplete but I think this may be a bit slow with 650-1000 images..

I also need an Idea on how to get a list of all words used (for auto-complete)

Comment: You shouldn't use a comma separated list stored in a column, if you want to search items of this list. Use a separate table instead.

Comment: so i should use another table with id, keyword.. and how do I connect them?

Comment: With a junction table image_keywords. This is the usual procedure for many to many relations.